# Benefits of WSO2 ESB over SYNAPSE

Tags: wso2, esb, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

Evaluating Synapse 2.1 and WSO2 esb 4.7.0. WSO2 ESB provides UI console which is a nice feature over Synapse. Apart from that, WSO2 esb built over synapse core features like Web Services Proxying, Caching, Protocol switching(SOAP to JSON), accessing HTTPS web service, Mediation & Fault Handlers. If interested only in core services, which one should we prefer **WSO2 ESB or Synapse ESB**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Criteria for choosing simple Apache Synapse Vs WSO2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30700917/criteria-for-choosing-simple-apache-synapse-vs-wso2)

Answer (score 0):

Apache  does not provide commercial support for Synapse. [WSO2](http://wso2.com/) ESB is using synapse as the mediation engine and it provides  commercial  support. If you are using core features of ESB, then you can use synapse, but if you face an issue, you have to wait until it get fixed in a newer release of synapse. 
You can better check the features which you need and select.