# Criteria for choosing simple Apache Synapse Vs WSO2

Tags: wso2, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

While evaluating various ESB's, I came across Apache Synapse & WSO2. In WSO2 it's mentioned that WSO2 completely uses Synapse and built on top of it.

However I am not still clear what additional features does WSO2 offer over Synapse? (Apart from commercial support).

One difference I could see is the web UI to manage proxy definitions, sequences creation etc. Are there any other features which WSO2 provides over Synapse? Also please share if there are any guidelines to choose between Synpase & WSO2

I just wanted to be sure why I am going to WSO2 over Synapse.

Thanks,
Harish

Comment: Hi.. I believe this is a very basic / FAQ type question to WSO2 community. Can you please give a couple of high level pointers (Important points) which will help my decision.. Kindly respond to this.. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

WSO2 ESB offer many great features on top of synapse. I am listing few here.

- Graphical management console to create/manage/monitor proxies/APIs and services.
- Support for many transports [1].
- Statistics, logging and auditing support
- Support for many content types
- And industry accepted proven performance.

List can go on and on. Hence I am referring you to WSO2 documentation on features[2]. Hope you can get some idea from there.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/ESB+Transports

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Features